# CSS image border rollover effect without resizing image?

Tags: css, image, hover, border

I'm almost afraid to ask this question because it seems like such an obvious one, but I just can't find a clear answer, so at the risk of tarnishing my non-existant reputation, here goes:

Is there a way to add an expanding CSS inner-border to an image on hover, without affecting the size of the image?

Here is my code as close as I can get on my own:

CSS

```
* {
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;
}

.media_item_container img {  
border: 3px solid #00205f;

-webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
 -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
   -o-transition: all .3s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
      transition: all .3s ease;
}

.media_item_container img:hover {
border: 10px solid #00205f;
}


.media_item_container a
{
font-weight:bold;
color:#000;
text-decoration:none;
font-size:13px;
}
.media_item_container a:hover
{
color:#fff;
}
```

HTML

```
<body bgcolor="#999999">
<div class="media_item_container">

    <div class="media_item_text">
    <a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/business-q-c-158-158-5.jpg" width="158" height="158" class="media_item_thumb" />
    <h3>E-Brochure: <em>Printable e-brochure</em></h3>
    DOWNLOAD »</a>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aKedV/

Just trying to determine if there is any way to do it without the image scaling down as the border size increases (I basically understand why this is happening, just can't seem to come up with a solution on my own).

And I should clarify when I ask if there is a way to do this, I assume there must be some way to do this, but I would love to know if there is a relatively easy way.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/aKedV/2/ ... or like this? http://jsfiddle.net/mVaXJ/

Comment: Thanks Josh, but I actually want it to be an inner-border...unless I am seeing something different than you, the Fiddle you posted added an outer border, that shifts around page content when it is moused over.

Comment: Thanks! And what do you know...I got points for asking a stupid question :P

Comment: Set the image as a CSS background, then the border will not affect it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mate this is the solution that I came up with. Had to Change some HTML and CSS up but this is my shot at it. Hope this helps mate, Cheers

http://jsfiddle.net/aKedV/3/

**HTML:**

```
<body bgcolor="#999999">
    <div class="media_item_container">
        <div class="media_item_text">
            <a href="#">
                <div class="border"  style="background: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/business-q-c-158-158-5.jpg);">
                </div>


<h3>E-Brochure: <em>Printable e-brochure</em></h3>
    DOWNLOAD »</a>

    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.border {
    -webkit-transition: all 500ms linear;
    -o-transition: all 500ms linear;
    -moz-transition: all 500ms linear;
    -ms-transition: all 500ms linear;
    -kthtml-transition: all 500ms linear;
    transition: all 500ms linear;
    width: 158px;
    height: 158px;
}
.border:hover {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 2px 10px #00205f;
   box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 2px 10px #00205f;
}
.media_item_container a
{
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:13px;
}
.media_item_container a:hover
{
    color:#fff;
}
```

Comment: Nice work! Sorry, but I'm 3 points away from being able to upvote your answer! Looks like you did it by using an inset shadow. I did try that but don't know why I couldn't get it to work on my own... Thank you so much for your help!! That is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I know this is an additional question, however still somewhat related...would there be a simple way of triggering that hover effect on the image when the text is hovered over? Thanks again!

Answer (score 7):

You can use outline instead of border.

```
outline:3px solid red;
outline-offset:-3px; //keeping it inside
```

and on hover

```
outline:10px solid red;
outline-offset:-10px;
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5Yka8/1)

Comment: That works great too! I would just make the offset one pixel less on each so that the border sits right up against the edge. Who knew it was this easy...SO rules!

Comment: @ElliottSamuelLemberger: You still looking to use border?

Comment: Thanks Lokesh. This answer, and Donte's answer below both worked to achieve this.

Comment: @ElliottSamuelLemberger Is there anything wrong with my answer Elliott?

Comment: No, it's great as I commented above. Thanks again!